# Embedded scrollview in tabbar item using storyboards won't scroll

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uistoryboard

For my current project I wanted to use storyboards and autolayout instead of coding everything by hand. It has gone well so far, but my design has a section of the app where there is a tab bar and one of those tab needs to show four views. The design is to swipe between the four and so I thought to use a scroll view. After some trial and error I found that embedding a Container View in the tab allowed me to easily set up a scroll view and put a couple of view inside it, carefully aligning them using positioning to put them side by side so that each page is one child view. I'm not sure how that plays with the autolayout, and in fact I have the problem that the scroll view won't scroll past the first page position. I can drag about 1/3 of the second page into view, but it never brings that page entirely in view.

I've checked the content size and offset and all of the view positions and it all seems correct. And when I use Spark Inspector to change the scroll offset to the position of the second view/page, the app shows the right page/view and I can even scroll back to the first page. I'm a bit perplexed as to what is causing it to not scroll properly. I don't have any code to show as this is all done in storyboards, but I am wondering if anyone has any ideas as to what is wrong?

Alternately, does anyone have an idea for how to use autolayout and storyboards to set up swiping four adjacent views in a tab? I suspect there are ways to do it. I can think of ways to do it in code, but I'm trying to avoid doing it that way.

EDIT: I set the scroll view delegate to the view controller around it and checked the values of `contentSize` on `scrollViewWillBeginDragging` and `scrollViewDidScroll`. It is always set to {0,0} even after I force set it on `viewDidLoad`. So I tried setting it every time `scrollViewWillBeginDragging` is called, which seems work, but I don't understand why this happens and it doesn't smell right. Is there some autolayout constraint that might account for this? Does something cause `contentSize` get set to {0,0} during the layout process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For lack of any other answer, I'll use my unsatisfying solution as an answer in the hopes that helps someone else in the future:

I set the scroll view delegate to the view controller around it and checked the values of `contentSize` on `scrollViewWillBeginDragging` and `scrollViewDidScroll`. It is always set to `{0,0}` even after I force set it on viewDidLoad. So I tried setting it every time `scrollViewWillBeginDragging` is called, which seems to work.

I'd love to know why the `contentSize` is being reset if anyone finds out!